# How to use ForeignKey, ManyToManyFields and other fields of Django Relational DB into MongoDB

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models, djongo

I am new in Django with MongoDB. Please suggest how to create models using MongoDB with relationship like ForeignKey, ManyToManyFields etc...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use MongoEngine for Django project

please refer MongoEngine document here: http://docs.mongoengine.org/index.html

using Mongoengine you can simply create a model like this:

```
class YourModel(Document): # Define Model in using MongoEngine
    id = IntField(unique=True) # define Integer field
    percentage = FloatField(default=0.00) # define float field
    user = ReferenceField('User') # foreignkey
```

All the fields are the same as Django as an ex: **IntField, FloatField** And You can use relational field (foreign key) using **ReferenceField**.

For more information, please follow the documentation (http://docs.mongoengine.org/index.html)

Comment: Can i go for djongo. It will work with the same models & views.

Comment: You need to change your model and views according to mongoEngine and views.
If you are using the Django rest framework then use **rest_framework_mongoengine* *.